# Radio button groups in ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat, radiobuttonlist

I have a list of items that contains organizations and each organization has two properties `TargetIsSelected` and `InfoIsSelected` which could be either `true` or `false` and are mutually exclusive. When the form loads I want the appropriate option to be selected for each organization row and when the user changes option I would like the changes updated in the underlying model for the respective organization.

My data looks like

```
$scope.Orgs = [{ "ID": "1", "Description": "Org 1", "TargetIsSelected": false, "InfoIsSelected": true },
               { "ID": "2", "Description": "Org 2", "TargetIsSelected": false, "InfoIsSelected": false },
               { "ID": "3", "Description": "Org 3", "TargetIsSelected": false, "InfoIsSelected": false }];
 });
```

and the HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    Target | Info 
    <div data-ng-repeat="org in Orgs">
       <input type="radio" name="org{{$parent.$index}}" ng-model="$parent.TargetIsSelected" data-ng-value={{org.TargetIsSelected}}>
       <input type="radio" name="org{{$parent.$index}}" ng-model="$parent.InfoIsSelected" data-ng-value={{org.InfoIsSelected}}>
       {{org.Description}}
        <br />
    </div>

   <br />
   {{ Orgs | json }}
```

The problem is the default option from data (`TargetIsSelected` and `InfoIsSelected`) is not selected  when the screen loads and changed option is not propagated to the model for each row. Currently I can select only one option from the entire list of options. I understand `ng-repeat` creates a child scope so I'm using `$parent` to reference the model but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated.

I have setup a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dFvd62A221WzvXYNVPKd?p=preview)

Comment: Doesn't make sense to have two separate properties and use radio buttons for this.

Comment: @dfsq you are correct, even if I bind to the same property for both the options I don't get the models updated for each row. The updated Plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WYNG2UnMLtMVtMOAwbrF?p=preview) . I just want to know which option is selected for each row.

Comment: Checkboxes would be better here: http://plnkr.co/edit/gORmTUluU6e3SZXOl8eb?p=preview